# The advantages of using a strand specific cDNA in RNA-Seq?

Tags: bioinformatics, rna-sequencing

May I ask what are the advantages of using a strand specific cDNA library in an RNA-seq experiment? as far as I know it can make us able to read the code region but what about other advantages?

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Please take the [guided tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) and then read [about how to ask a good question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). You will see that you are expected to "Search and Research" before posting. I quickly found a paper on this topic by Googling. If the papers you have found don't answer your question, reference them, say what they do say and why that is insufficient or not what you are after. Otherwise I am afraid your question is likely to be removed.

Comment: Hi, I have already google it before posting this question but it is still not clear to me what are the other advantages. Even when you think my question could be basic and silly I still need someone to answer this question in a simple way please.

Comment: It is not a question of whether the question is basic or silly, and I did not say that. What I did was review your first post — as is standard practice here — and explained how the site worked giving links, using standard language. I know you haven't completed the introductory tour as you do not have the badge for doing so. If you want to use this site you must follow its rules. Please read them.